# Use DbInitializer to add a new model into the Database

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I wonder what is the proper way to add a new model into the database and populate it with the proper values without the need of constructing a whole new View inside the project.

My database is already created and is been updated through the Views of the project.

This is the `DbInitializer` at the moment:

```
 public class DbInitializer
 {
    public static void Initialize(PlataformaContext context)
    {
        context.Database.EnsureCreated();

        if (context.MachineTypes.Any())
        {
            return; //DB has been seeded
        }

        var familias = new MachineFamily[]
            {
                new MachineFamily{FamilyDescription="Cama Saltarina"},
                new MachineFamily{FamilyDescription="Hockey"},
                new MachineFamily{FamilyDescription="Kiddie"},
                new MachineFamily{FamilyDescription="Mini Carrusel"},
                new MachineFamily{FamilyDescription="Peluchera"},
                new MachineFamily{FamilyDescription="Redemption"},
                new MachineFamily{FamilyDescription="Simulador"},
            };
        foreach (MachineFamily f in familias)
        {
            context.MachineFamilies.Add(f);
        }
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
 }
```

So far I only update the database thru migrations if I were to add a new model or property, but I would like to add a new model with a set of values, can I re-use the `DbInitializer` for this without dropping the current database? How should it be edited? I'm afraid that if I change it I might overwrite some part of it.

Comment: can you explain more. Do you mean using initializer again without droping the database?

Comment: yes! without dropping the database. I believe this might be the only way to add a new model and initialize it's values without creating a new view. I may be wrong

Comment: It is possible to change the database in mssql, and then update entity framework model, and finaly feed the database. But I think I am not answering your question.

Comment: not quite, but thanks tho! it's hard for me to image what you just told me since I haven't done it before

Answer (score 0):

Well, you should be able to re-utilize your `DbInitiliazer`. Just change it a little bit so that you can seed more than just one entity:

```
public class DbInitializer
{
    public static void Initialize(PlataformaContext context)
    {
        context.Database.EnsureCreated();

        if (!context.MachineTypes.Any())
        {
            var familias = new MachineFamily[] { ... };
            // No need for foreach, AddRange does it for you
            context.MachineFamilies.AddRange(familias);
        }

        if (!context.SomeOtherTypes.Any())
        {
            var someOtherType = new SomeOtherType[] { ... };
            context.SomeOtherTypes.AddRange(someOtherType );
        }

        context.SaveChanges();
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Will give it a try